# How to calculate coordinates of tangent points?

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

I need to make a svg file for a project and I need some parameters that I haven't figured out how to calculate yet.
I have a point of coordinates **x1,y1** and a circumference with a center of coordinates **x2,y2** with radius **r**. The point x1,y1 is outside the circumference. How do I calculate the coordinates of the points belonging to the circumference (**x3,y3** and **x4,y4**) from which the two tangent lines would pass? The outer point (x1,y1) will never touch the circumference and will never belong to the circumference.
This is the **drawing** to make the concept better understood, in **red** the values to be calculated.
[Tangents scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRJj3.png)

Comment: The center of the circle is P2(x2, y2), the radius is r. The unknown point P3(x3, y3) satisfies the equation of the circle: *(x3-x2)^2 + (y3-y2)^2 = r^2* **(1)**.

Comment: The tangent P1(x1,y1)<->P3(x3,y3) is perpendicular to the radius of the circle (x2,y2)<->(x3,y3). So apply the Pythagorean theorem to the triangle of P1, P2, P3; the distance between P1 and P2 is (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2, the distance between P1 and P3 is (x1-x3)^2 + (y1-y3)^2 and P2-P3 is r, the radius =>  *(x1-x3)^2 + (y1-y3)^2 + r^2 = (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2* **(2)**

Comment: Solve equations **(1)** and **(2)** for x3 and y3. It will reduce to two 2nd degree equations, one for x3 and the other for y3. Each equation will have two solutions iff P1 is outside the circle; the two solutions actually correspond to P3 and P4.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions . I tried everything today but could not find a solution. In my post I have included a link to a more explanatory image. the values in red are the ones to be calculated.

Comment: Both my solution from comments and @MBo's in the answer are correct, apply to your image and give you a solution. Please let me know if you want it in some programming language or what kind of verification you're struggling to comply with.

Comment: I am creating a function in python that passing the known values (x1,y1,x2,y2 and r) returns a tuple with the 4 values to be calculated(x3,y3 x4,y4) .These values I will need for drawings in svg format . For the programming issue there are no problems , the problem is mathematical . I don't remember anything about trigonometry and second degree equations.

Comment: @Rolens Centottantaquattro I added code

Comment: @RolensCentottantaquattro Are you aware about answer accepting? I see that you have never accepted answers. It is worth to choose useful one and set green mark.

Answer (score 0):

Shift coordinate system to make origin in circle center (to get simpler equations). Now point is

```
 x1' = x1 - x2
 y1' = y1 - y2
```

Solve the next equation system (point belongs to circumference and radius is perpendicular to tangent)

```
x^2 + y^2 = r^2
(x - x1') * x + (y - y1') * y = 0
```

for unknown x, y.

To get final result, add `x2, y2` to solution results (should be two solutions)

```
import math
def tangpts(px, py, cx, cy, r):
    px -= cx
    py -= cy
    r2 = r*r
    r4 = r2*r2
    a = px*px+py*py
    b = -2*r2*px
    c = r4 - r2*py*py
    d = b*b-4*a*c
    if d < 0:
        return None
    d = math.sqrt(d)
    xx1 = (-b - d) / (2*a)
    xx2 = (-b + d) / (2*a)
    if (abs(py) > 1.0e-8):
        yy1 = (r2 - px * xx1) / py
        yy2 = (r2 - px * xx2) / py
    else:
        yy1 = math.sqrt(r2 - xx1*xx1)
        yy2 = -yy1

    return((xx1+cx,yy1+cy),(xx2+cx,yy2+cy))

print(tangpts(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 1))
print(tangpts(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
print(tangpts(0, 0, -3, -3, 3))
print(tangpts(2, 0, 0, 0, 1))
print(tangpts(0, 1, 0, 0, 1))

>>>
None             #point inside 
((0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0))    #common case
((-3.0, 0.0), (0.0, -3.0))   #common case
((0.5, 0.8660254037844386), (0.5, -0.8660254037844386))   #py is zero case
((0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0))  # single tangent case - point at circumference
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to post the python code for the solution, I'm copying the explanation originally in comments:

1. The center of the circle is P<sub>2</sub>(x2, y2), the radius is r. The unknown point P<sub>3</sub>(x3, y3) satisfies the equation of the circle:

   *(x3-x2)^2 + (y3-y2)^2 = r^2*  **(1)**.
2. The tangent P<sub>1</sub>P<sub>3</sub> is perpendicular to the radius of the circle P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>3</sub>. So apply the Pythagorean theorem to the triangle P<sub>1</sub>P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>3</sub>:

   a) the distance between P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> is (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2,

   b) the distance between P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>3</sub> is (x1-x3)^2 + (y1-y3)^2

   c) the distance P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>3</sub> is r, the radius

   *(x1-x3)^2 + (y1-y3)^2 + r^2 = (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2* **(2)**

We have thus to solve the equations (1) and (2) for x3 and y3.

We now separate the unknowns (a linear relation between x3 and y3 can be obtained by (1)-(2) => *(x3-x2)(x1-x2) + (y3-y2)(y1-y2) = r^2*), and we get the two equations of second degree.

The python implementation:

```python
import math
def tangentPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2, r):
  a = (y1-y2)**2+(x1-x2)**2
  bx = -r**2 * (x1-x2)
  cx = r**2 * (r**2-(y1-y2)**2)
  sqDeltax = math.sqrt(bx**2 - a*cx)
  x3 = x2 + (-bx + sqDeltax)/a
  x4 = x2 + (-bx - sqDeltax)/a
  
  by = -r**2 * (y1-y2)
  cy = r**2 * (r**2 - (x1-x2)**2)
  sqDeltay = math.sqrt(by**2 - a*cy)
  y3 = y2 + (-by - sqDeltay)/a
  y4 = y2 + (-by + sqDeltay)/a

  return (x3, y3), (x4, y4)
```